# LoadURL WebView based on Drawer click

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, navigation-drawer

I'm a beginner at Android and am currently developing a proof-of-concept app which has a drawer with items which when clicked load a certain URL into the WebView which is part of the main layout. I'm having trouble loading the different URLs when clicking on the items. How would I solve this?

I'm using Mike Penz's [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library and the following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Drawer mDrawer = null;
private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
private WebView mWebView = null;
private TextView mTextView = null;

private WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get TextView
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);

    // Handle Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Set the WebView
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://radio.iium.edu.my/v5/");


    // Create the header
    // Create the AccountHeader
    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withCompactStyle(false)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.fmheader)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();

    mDrawer = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_stream).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_microphone),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_contact).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_envelope),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_about).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_social_section_header).withEnabled(false),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_facebook).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_facebook_official),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_twitter).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_twitter),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_youtube).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_youtube_play)
            ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer

            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    /*if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }*/
                    if (drawerItem != null) {
                        if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                            mTextView.setText("Home");
                        } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {
                            mTextView.setText("Live Stream");
                        } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 3) {
                            mTextView.setText("Facebook");
                            mWebView.stopLoading();
                            mWebView.clearCache(true);
                            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
                        } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 4) {
                            mTextView.setText("Twitter");
                            mWebView.stopLoading();
                            mWebView.clearCache(true);
                            mWebView.loadUrl("https://twitter.com");
                        } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 5) {
                            mTextView.setText("YouTube");
                            mWebView.stopLoading();
                            mWebView.clearCache(true);
                            mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
            .build();

    mDrawer.openDrawer();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
    outState = mDrawer.saveInstanceState(outState);
    //add the values which need to be saved from the accountHeader to the bundle
    outState = headerResult.saveInstanceState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
    if (mDrawer != null && mDrawer.isDrawerOpen()) {
        mDrawer.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

And the following is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </WebView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by replacing `drawerItem.getIdentifier()` with `position` as follows:

```
if (drawerItem != null) {
    if (position == 1) {
        mTextView.setText("Home");
    } else if (position == 2) {
          mTextView.setText("Live Stream");
    } else if (position == 3) {
          mTextView.setText("Facebook");
          mWebView.stopLoading();
          mWebView.clearCache(true);
          mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
    } else if (position == 4) {
          mTextView.setText("Twitter");
          mWebView.stopLoading();
          mWebView.clearCache(true);
          mWebView.loadUrl("https://twitter.com");
    } else if (position == 5) {
          mTextView.setText("YouTube");
          mWebView.stopLoading();
          mWebView.clearCache(true);
          mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
    }
}
```